# Shopware 6 App template - API calls to the store return 302 instead of 200

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

I created shopware plugin in the App template system. Everything works well but during testing on the test environment in the shopware account. According to the docs, they run this exact docker [image](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-apps#app-descriptions-in-your-shopware-account). I noticed an issue that all requests from the external server to the shopware(for example to get some configuration data) is returning 302 instead 200.

I tried different endpoints e.g:

- api/_action/system-config?domain=myPluginDomain
- api/version
  Every endpoint that I did try return 302 instead of 200.

When I tested the same endpoints in the POSTMAN I got the correct response with status 200 but here I am using the bearer token. In the app, on the backend side, I am using built-in functionality for [authorization](https://github.com/shopware/AppTemplate). It looks like that connection by integration returns 302

When I tried the app on a different server(not Docker) everything works well and got 200 status with the proper body.

PS. It looks like I am not the only one - [github](https://github.com/shopware/AppTemplate/issues/15)